# Bash replace minor version in version string

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm looking for an elegant way (a bash one-liner) to replace a part of a semantic version number. The versions look like 7.12.0-0. I need to replace the minor version with a number that's two more than what's in the string.

- Original string: 7.12.0-0
- Resulting string 7.14.0-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With awk:

```
echo "7.12.0-0" | awk -F. '{print $1"."($2+2)"."$3}'
>7.14.0-0
```

or

```
echo "7.12.0-0" | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="."}{$2+=2}1'
>7.14.0-0
```

Comment: Since we're golfing, the second one could use `$2+=2` ;)

Comment: @BenjaminW. That's what I was missing! Will update to complete the putt.

Answer (score 2):

plain bash

```sh
ver="7.12.0-0"

# split on dots into the "parts" array
IFS="." read -ra parts <<<"$ver"

# increment the 2nd array element
((parts[1] += 2))

# join on dots
newver=$(IFS="."; echo "${parts[*]}")

echo $newver     # => 7.14.0-0
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine all that into a one-liner?

Comment: No, but it can go into a function.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu sed`:

```sh
s='7.12.0-0'
sed -E 's/^([0-9]*\.)([0-9]+)(\..+)/echo \1$((\2+2))\3/e' <<< "$s"

7.14.0-0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only bash variable expansion and `cut`:

```sh
v=17.12.0-0
add=2
echo ${v%%.*}.$(( $add + $(echo $v | cut -d . -f 2) )).${v##*.}
# output 17.14.0-0
```